# How to save parts of linprog solutions

Tags: scipy

I am solving a serie of linear programing problems using linprog by indexing each problem in a for-loop:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
for i in range(1,N):
    sol[i] = linprog(coa3[N][0], A_ub = coa4[i], b_ub = chvneg[i],  options=      {"disp": True})
```

I would like to save in a list (still indexed over i) the function minimization result and the array displaying the values of the variables. I guess I need to add in the for-loop something like minfval[i] = ??? and xval[i] = ???, but actually I don't know how to extract these values from the results provided by linprog. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reading the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-simplex.html) as it's pretty clearly explained what exactly linprog returns.

The good thing is, that you are actually storing these values with your code already because you are storing the whole **scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult**.

It's now just a matter of accessing it:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
for i in range(1,N):
    sol[i] = linprog(coa3[N][0], A_ub = coa4[i], b_ub = chvneg[i],  options=      {"disp": True})

# iterate over solution-vectors
for i in range(1,N):
    print(sol[i].x)

# iterate over objectives
for i in range(1,N):
    print(sol[i].fun)
```

You should also check out the field `success` just to be safe!

Extraction of the docs (link above) on what is contained in linprog's result:

```
x : ndarray
    The independent variable vector which optimizes the linear
    programming problem.
fun : float
    Value of the objective function.
slack : ndarray
    The values of the slack variables.  Each slack variable corresponds
    to an inequality constraint.  If the slack is zero, then the
    corresponding constraint is active.
success : bool
    Returns True if the algorithm succeeded in finding an optimal
    solution.
status : int
    An integer representing the exit status of the optimization::
     0 : Optimization terminated successfully
     1 : Iteration limit reached
     2 : Problem appears to be infeasible
     3 : Problem appears to be unbounded
nit : int
    The number of iterations performed.
message : str
    A string descriptor of the exit status of the optimization.
```